# Remove blank line on every web page

Tags: php, html

I have 3 blank lines at the beginning of every page that is causing errors of an add-on with stamps.com. (PS I have worked closely with their support team).
I can see the lines using firebug, but don't know which file is causing them.
I am trying to REMOVE these lines but can't seem to locate them in the header and main_page php files, for templates, common and default folders.

I am using version 1.3.8a of Zen Cart.

The web site is pranajewelry.com

Any suggestions on which files in order of precedence and what special code I should look for?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure *all* output buffering is of.
2. Call `headers_sent($file,$line);` at a point in time you *know* you already sent output (doesn't matter where, it can be at the end of the request).
3. Voilà, $file & $line hold the position where output started.

If the return of `headers_sent` is true, but `$line==0`, you'll have to look into `auto_prepend`s.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the suggestions above due to my limited coding experience. Further basic information requested on where, how to use above?

Comment: @Dan: it is only 1 suggestion, with a step-by-step plan. Possibly you can skip (1), just add the code in (2) somewhere at the end of a file that produces output / html, and echo/var_dump the `$file` & `$line` variables: they will show a filename & linenumber where the first output of the request started. Don't keep the `headers_sent` function in there after you've traced & corrected the 3-line problem, it just helps you determine _where_ the output comes from, it is not a solution to prevent the output of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that those 3 blank lines cause problems with anything.

Anyway, they could be just about anywhere.  Look for any lines in your files that aren't within PHP tags.  You could have a common include for example that has 3 blank lines at the end of it.  It could be anything.  Typically, it will be before or after your `<?php ?>` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say those lines would have to be in one of your first includes in your template. Quite possibly you may have whitespace outside of you `<?php ?>` blocks for your configuration or function include files.

Comment: I was able to find one of the lines as there was whitespace in the html_header.php file. Still struggling with the additional lines

Comment: @Dan - they will be in similar places. You may want to check all header files and be aware of any line breacks between ?> blocks. Even include files will generate line breaks if they appear outside the ?>.

Answer (score 0):

Locate this in your files in the directory (use search in files) and you will probably find the blank lines

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">
```

Comment: how do I search for blank lines using Notepad++.

Comment: This helped get rid of one line. Can't seem to find the other lines

Answer (score 0):

hey if you want to remove blank line then replace that web page/s with "notepad++ software".
it has advance text processing capability. or remove it with "macromedia dreamweaver 8.0"
it has tag replacing options with you can replace blank lines present in all pages in website folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to look *after* your closing `?>` as well.  Anything after it will be sent to output; this is actually a good reason why you *shouldn't* use the closing `?>` at the end of your PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Dreamweaver try this out

1. Open the file
2. Click CTRL + F
3. Select "Current document" in "Find in" (You can also select the folder if you have multiple files)
4. Search in "Source code"
5. Tick "Use regular expression"
6. Type "[\r\n]{2,}"(without quotes) in "Find"
7. Type "\n" (without quotes) in "Replace"
8. Press "Replace All